# Undefined Function Error when using Jasmine

Tags: jasmine

I thought I made good headway by coding a Jasmine mock like this. But I couldn't fix this error.

How does the spyOn method actually work ? In fact this method seems to widely used. Has something changed in 2.0

```
describe('Test Controller', function() {

var $scope, $rootScope, $q, controller, mockService, queryDeferred;

//What is the expected response ?
var expectedResponse = [{ suffix: 'Mr.'}, { prefix: 'Miss'}];

beforeEach(function () {
  angular.module("Test", []);
});

beforeEach(module('Test'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$q_, $controller) {
      $q = _$q_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();


      mockService = {
        query: function() {
          queryDeferred = $q.defer();
          return queryDeferred.promise;
        }
      }


      spyOn(mockService, 'query').andCallThrough();

      // inject the mocked Service into the controller.
      controller = $controller('TestController', {
        '$scope': $scope,
        'ServiceApi': mockService
      });



}));

});


TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (d:/karma-requirejs-Angular/test/PromiseSpec.j
s:34:39)
        at Object.invoke (d:/karma-requirejs-Angular/lib/angular/angular.js:
4152:17)
        at Object.workFn (d:/karma-requirejs-Angular/lib/angular-mocks/angul
ar-mocks.js:2255:20)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (d:/karma-requirejs-Angular/lib
/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2226:25)
        at Suite.<anonymous> (d:/karma-requirejs-Angular/test/PromiseSpec.js
:20:16)
        at d:/karma-requirejs-Angular/test/PromiseSpec.js:7:3
        at Object.context.execCb (d:/karma-requirejs-Angular/node_modules/re
 quirejs/require.js:1658:33)
        at Object.Module.check (d:/karma-requirejs-Angular/node_modules/requ
```

Update :

I am posting this working code as an answer. I fixed a few issues.

```
describe('Test Controller', function() {

    var $q,
        $rootScope,
        $scope,
        mockService,
        mockResponse = [{ suffix: 'Mr.'}, { prefix: 'Miss'}];



    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$q_,
                               _$rootScope_) {
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        mockService = {
            query: function() {
                queryDeferred = $q.defer();
                return {$promise: queryDeferred.promise};
            }
        }

         spyOn(mockService, 'query').and.callThrough();

         $controller('TestCtrl', {
           '$scope': $scope,
           'testService': mockService
         });

    }));

    describe('Given a setup for the invocation of the mock query', function() {
            beforeEach(function() {
                queryDeferred.resolve(mockResponse);
                $rootScope.$apply();
            });

           it('When the call to the mock service is issued ', function() {

               resolvespy = jasmine.createSpy('resolve');
               rejectspy = jasmine.createSpy('reject');

               expect(mockService.query).toHaveBeenCalled();

               var q = $scope.getPromise();

               q.then(resolvespy,rejectspy);

               queryDeferred.resolve(mockResponse);
               $rootScope.$apply();


               expect(resolvespy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockResponse);
               expect(rejectspy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

           });

           it('Then the mock service should have returned the correct response', function() {

              expect($scope.test).toBe(mockResponse);
          });

            it('Then the mock service should have returned the correct response', function() {

                expect($scope.testfunction).toBeDefined();
            });

            it("should do something else when something happens", function() {
                $scope.testfunction();
                expect($scope.value).toBe('value');
            });
      });

});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

WIth Jasmine 2.0 you should replace:

```
andCallThrough();
```

with:

```
and.callThrough();
```

See:
[Jasmine 2.0 documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) and [Upgrading to 2.0](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html)

Comment: I updated my question with my working code. I made the change suggested by you too.